When would KDC server not send this to client KDC_ERR_RESPONSE_TOO_BIG
Basically, i wanted to test a scenario where domain join should fail with UDP when KDC server doesnt send KDC_ERR_RESPONSE_TOO_BIG as the response so that client cannot switch to TCP.
Hence wanted to know what setting is done in domain controller so that it doesnt send the KDC_ERR_RESPONSE_TOO_BIG event to the client.
Not Sure about that .
